# How I can use several normal maps for one mesh with several UV maps?

Tags: modeling, node-editor, normal-map

I have several UV maps for one mesh:

[image]

For every UV map I have baked NORMAL map. How can I connect them all to my mesh?

[image]

Comment: why didn't you use one unique normal map? you could try to use some Color > MixRGB nodes in Mix mode, but I'm not sure that it will work as you may have overlapping maps

Comment: Or you can use four shaders and mix them with mix shader.

Comment: I use several UV maps because it was shown in tutorial about uv unwrapping, I thought this way can give higher resolution when I will do texturing

Comment: why not use a larger image if you want a good resolution?

Comment: Why my normal map does not cover mesh in the correct way 
img of problem: ibb.co/SnSpJ6W

Comment: problem: https://ibb.co/SnSpJ6W

Comment: I don't know how your UVs are organized and how your normal maps look like so it's hard to say, I'm not familiar with your method, maybe do something simpler, one unique unwrap and one unique normal map, create a larger image if you want enough resolution

Comment: I post images of issue in this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227324/why-normal-map-does-not-cover-mesh-properly

Comment: maybe share your file if you want us to test, don't forget to pack the images and share here: https://pasteall.org/blend/