# Why normal map does not cover mesh properly?

Tags: normal-map

normal map is strange and shifted
[image: IT SHIFTED]

but in uv editor normal map cover my UV unwrapping correctly (hard to see):
[image]

Comment: It's possible those image nodes are defaulting to the generated coordinate space.  You need a *Texture Coordinate* node, and attach UV to the input vector of the image nodes.

Comment: first thing, as you've created a UV map for this normal map, plug the UV Map node you've created into the Image Texture node (it's not the case on your screenshot)